# Vanilla JS - DOM Reflow Within Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am writing a logo slider in vanilla JS that pushes the logos to one direction and then resets position upon completion.  I've decided to disable the animation upon reset so it looks seamless.  However to disable the animation, I have to force a DOM reflow after removing the animation class.  This isn't working as expected, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas either regarding the reflow or general implementation?

Thanks!

```
var sliderLength = document.getElementsByClassName("badgeSealIcon").length;
var sliderContainer = document.getElementById("badge-container");
var sliderMargin = 0;
var sliderIndex = 0;
sliderLength /= 2;

setInterval(animateSlide, 1000);

function animateSlide() {
  if( sliderIndex <  sliderLength){
        sliderIndex += 1;
        sliderMargin -= 100;
        var stringMargin = '';
        var stringMargin = sliderMargin + 'px';
        document.getElementById("badge-container").style.marginLeft = stringMargin;
  }else{
        sliderContainer.classList.remove("badgeTransition");
        void document.getElementById("badge-container").offsetWidth;
        document.getElementById("badge-container").style.marginLeft = '-100px';
        //setTimeout(function(){
            //document.getElementById("badge-container").classList.add("badgeTransition");
        //}, 100);
        sliderIndex = 0;
        sliderMargin = -100;
  }
};
```

```css
#badge-parent{
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#badge-container{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}
.badgeSealIcon{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 12px;
}
.badgeTransition{
    transition: margin .5s;
}
```

Comment: Why not use CSS animations?

Comment: You can bind to the `transitionend` event. Also you could use template strings to skip creating `stringMargin`. `...marginLeft = \`${sliderMargin}px\``

Comment: Please show your CSS too. It's very unclear what you expected the reflow to do here. If, as the class name implies, the `transition` property is set through the `.badgeTransition` rule, then triggering a reflow is useless when you remove it.

Comment: @Kaiido yes I am attempting to remove the `transition` property via the `.badgeTransition` rule, I was under the assumption that using the reflow would stop the animation, at the moment the animation still plays even if the rule is removed.

@YaakovAinspan I am using JS to move the items and a CSS transition to animate the move, I wasn't sure if I could use pure CSS transforms as the amount of logos varies per page

Comment: What animation? Currently there is no transition anymore, as soon as you remove this class, no need for a reflow here: https://jsfiddle.net/7fzy3459/ A reflow would be needed only to get an updated state of the CSSOM before starting a new transition, and thus before setting new positions that were not yet treated by the CSS engine. But if you are talking of "animation" as the fact that they keep changing positions, even without transitions, then that's because your JS setInterval is still running. Call clearInterval to stop it.